# How to trigger / open native menu on select menu in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, select

How can i open the select menu below using jquery programatically

```
<select id="selectMenu">        
 <option value="" class="first">c</option>       
 <option value="" class="">c++</option>       
 <option value="" class="">java</option> 
</select>
```

I have tried code

```
<script>
 $(document).on("pageinit", "#Test", function(e){
 $('.testSelect').on('tap',function() {
// $('#selectMenu').click();
 $('#selectMenu').selectmenu();
// $('#selectMenu').selectmenu('refresh');
 $('#selectMenu').selectmenu( "open" );
 $('#selectMenu').trigger("click");
 });
 });
</script>
```

but neither helped for me, its working for the non-native menu for select options (i.e. when i used data-native-menu= "false" but not working for what I am looking for.)

The real problem is i want to use image as select menu button which will show native menu of select tag on desktop browser as well as on mobile devices

So I am thinking on click of image i'll open select menu (native menu) and I have hide select menu tag.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

To use image as select menu button in jquery one need to override jquery classes which jquery add while creating the select menu.

No need to change jquery .css file just override them (properties / attribite) using style attribute of the tag.

use following code to do this it worked for me ->

```
<div class="ui-select">
    <div data-icon="none" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn" style="margin: 0px; text-align: inherit;">
            <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="../../images/image.png" style="">           
        <select id="selectMenuCls" data-native-menu="true" size="0" data-role="none">         
            <option value="" class="first">c</option>       
            <option value="" class="">c++</option>       
            <option value="" class="">java</option> 
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

please note that in select tag data-role="none" attribute is essential so that jquery will not apply it's custom classes to select menu